# yii2 composer.phar update is not working

Tags: windows, composer-php, yii2

I'm using xampp on Windows 8 and I want to run `composer.phar update` for installing `Yii2-user`according do the description here:

```
http://yii2-user.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/installation.html
```

But when I do that, no update happens.
Instead, I got shown the version number of composer and a list of the possible commands with composer.
There is no error-message and `update` is in the list of the possible commands.

I have tried `composer update` too, but with that I'm getting an error message:

```
  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stabl
e -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.0 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stabl
e -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stabl
e -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0
.0, 2.0.1].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> f
or more details.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you missed execution of this command:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

It should be executed only once.

You can find more information about it in official [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer) and plugin Github [page](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/).

Answer (score -1):

this problem is recursive since 2014, like other than AssetsManager,  permissions .... and somes php Warning or Fatal, at the begin of installation. I do not know how "Composer" elsewhere. But frankly with Yii2 is a calamity. Then as yii2 already does not need it for bugs. The accumulation of 2 it is a disaster. So...

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0"
```

With ~ you get the last version of composer-asset-plugin...
But that's often not enought !!!!